# session is not echoed when redirect

Tags: php, html, sql

At my main page i have the following code:

```
<?php
$required = array('post_question');
// making sure post field is not empty
$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
$error = true;
}
}
if(isset($_POST['post_question'])){
if ($error) {
echo "please type your question and submit!";
} else {
session_start();
$ps = $_POST['post_question'];
$_SESSION['postquestion']=$_GET['ps'];
header("Location: http://localhost/voidportals/success.php");
}     
}
?>
```

I have the corresponding form on same page.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
<input type="text" placeholder="ask your question!"  class="assin assin-success assin-autosize" name="post_question">
<input type="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

and then as you see my php code runs and redirects to another php page

```
<?php
$pss = "";
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['ps'])){
$pss = $_SESSION['ps'];
}   
echo $_SESSION['pss'];
?>
```

now the echo doesn't echo the pss. I have never used session before and have no clue what goes wrong.Can anybody help me.

I'm getting the following error:
`undefined index pss error.`

Comment: did you `session_start` on first page?

Comment: your session_start() at your main page is missing?

Comment: sorry. session start added. still not working. editted code lines with session edit

Comment: and is this going to be for wan access? otherwise you might want to re-consider your redirect url.

Comment: it is in testing phase so it achieved using wamp as of now

Comment: your form use "post", you trying to use $_GET to set session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have never set `$_SESSION['ps']` in your code.
set it as shown in below code and also always `exit();` after you set `header('location:')` Otherwise the script execution is not terminated. Setting another header alone is not enough to redirect.

```
<?php
$required = array('post_question');
// making sure post field is not empty
$error = false;
foreach ($required as $field) {
    if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $error = true;
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['post_question'])) {
    if ($error) {
        echo "please type your question and submit!";
    } else {
        session_start();
        $ps = $_POST['post_question'];
        $_SESSION['ps'] = $ps;
        header("Location: http://localhost/voidportals/success.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

and in 2nd page:

```
<?php
$pss = "";
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['ps'])){
    $pss = $_SESSION['ps'];
}
echo $pss;
?>
```

Comment: What is `ps` named element in your html?

Comment: $ps = $_POST['post_question'];
$_SESSION['postquestion']=$_GET['ps'];

Comment: i donno  how this works but im saving the post_question from input field to ps as session

Comment: but you never set `$_SESSION['ps']`?

Comment: $_SESSION['ps'] = $_GET['ps']; is this any different?

Comment: thanks very much vicky :D that works just the way i want :) last edit from you fixed it